# Dashboards for Portal Users?

Tags: visualforce, partner-portal

Anyone have a creative way to provide Dashboards to Partner Portal Users?  I'm looking at Visualforce Charts, but want to hear from someone who has provided Dashboards to Partner Portal users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't provide dashboards to partner portal users - if you look at the partner portal help page:

https://na6.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/partner_portal_about.htm

This defines the capabilities of the partner portal license.  This includes reports but unfortunately not dashboards.  This isn't something that you can game using Visualforce controllers running in system context or the like, as the platform still validates that the license type allows access to the functionality.

What is confusing is that you can add the dashboard tab to the portal, but that doesn't allow access to the dashboards themselves.

You could pass on dashboard snapshots if you set up a scheduled refresh and email the results, by forwarding on the email.  However, if you want the users to be able to access the information on demand, then you need to go the Visualforce route.

There's an idea for this that has quite a few votes:

https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqw3AAC

however, there are no comments from product management so that suggests to me that its not something that is being looked at right now.

Comment: any idea if it's supported in communities? What about the visualforce chart component as opposed to the dashbaord.