# Does apex:chart work for a partner portal/communities user?

Tags: visualforce, partner-communities, visualforce-charting

I've seen a few [posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/dashboards-for-portal-users) on here to get dashboards displayed to portal users and things of that nature, but I'm looking specifically for whether or not this tag works for communities users.

We've setup our page, and the chart displays perfectly fine for non-portal users. However when we log in as a portal user we get the following error:

> error: You can’t view the report chart because of an error. If the problem continues, contact salesforce.com Customer Support with as much information as you have, including the error code {0}, so that we can try to reproduce and fix the problem.

I've opened a case with support, but wanted to see if the SFSE community has any experience with this. I've confirmed the profile has access to run reports and I've confirmed the report folder is shared with all users including portal users. Here is the relevant part of the page:

```
    <div class="table-title">
        <h1>Team Statistics by Business Segment</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main-chart-container">
        <div class="calendar">
            <apex:inputText value="{!selectedDateRange}" styleClass="date-range" style="width:400px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="chart-1">
            <p>Chart 1</p>
            <!-- <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.clientportal_icons, 'ic_salesforces_client_portal/graphics/chart1.png')}" style="width:260px;" alt="MBO Logo" /> -->
            <analytics:reportChart developerName="Spending_by_Segment_STeam" size="small" cacheResults="false" showRefreshButton="false"  />    <!-- filter="[{column:'ACCOUNT_ID',operator:'equals', value:'{!acctId}'}]" -->
        </div>
        <div class="chart-2">
            <p>Chart 2</p>
            <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.clientportal_icons, 'ic_salesforces_client_portal/graphics/chart2.png')}" style="width:350px;" alt="MBO Logo" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Might be some permission related to fields and object permissions for community users

Comment: Thanks @MohithShrivastava, I'll make sure to go through again and confirm. I'm assuming if I can login as the portal user and run the reports then permissions are good. I took a look at sharing rules and permissions and confirmed it's all good, but it is possible I missed something.

Comment: Look at FLS ,System permissions .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, sure enough. A whole table didn't have read access. I could have sworn it was available. Anyway, if you want to thrown answer down there... I guess this is more of a specific use case though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just added as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was permission related .For portal Users ,if object Read permission is missing the dashboards using analytic:reportChart might throw internal server error .So check for all permissions to be 100% sure when you get these errors specific for profiles .